# MySQL Workbench: including triggers in creation script

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm using forward engineering to save a script that creates my database, but I also have some triggers that I want included in that. Thing is, triggers are defined in the Schema tab while forward engineering is done in the Model tab.

I need to be able to send the whole database creation script to someone so they can create it on their end. I know how to apply triggers to the database on my end, but I don't know how to include them in the creation script besides just sending the trigger scripts separately.

Is it as simple as putting the trigger statements at the end of the database creation script (generated by forward engineering)?

Comment: Prep a test database. Export the database, send the export to the other person

Comment: @RiggsFolly don't understand what you mean

Comment: Build your DB with your forward Engineered tables structure. Manually add the triggers to this database. Load any static data you may require. Then backup the database and deliver the backup to your other user

Comment: I just tried that, but the triggers are nowhere to be found in the dumped files. I even checked the "Dump Triggers" option.

Comment: What are you using to do the export?

Comment: Management > Data Export

Comment: Oh right, MySQL Workbench, of course silly me

Comment: On the Data Export screen Look for `Objects to Export` One of those is `Dump Triggers` its not checked by default. So check it dear liza, dear liza _Check it !_

Comment: In my previous comment I said that I did check that option.

Comment: Then look closer at the dump. Open it in an editor and search for the word `TRIGGER`

Comment: Like this example `DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`admin`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `test`.`bans_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `bans` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

END */;;`

Comment: They are dumped just after the table is created and any data is inserted in the dump file

Comment: It's working now, thanks

Comment: You mean it was always working! Those bits in the dump are a bit difficult to pick up until you see the first one

Answer (score 0):

you dump database using -

To dump all databases, invoke 
mysqldump with the --all-databases option:

```
mysqldump --all-databases > dump.sql
```

Here’s the command to dump the triggers and stored procedures for a database:

```
mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt [dbname]
```

hope its helpful to you.